# How do I create a jTable with information from an arrayList in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/535db68625fdb1e46deb

Hi!  So my program's purpose is to keep track of club rosters.  Currently I am trying to build a GUI.  I would like a jTable filled with information found in the Club and Student objects.  The table would have 3 columns, the instance fields of the Students.  Each row would be a different Student.  The information would come from each Club's roster arrayList.  A dropdown menu would select different clubs, replacing the data in the table.  I have read some stuff on how to create a TableModel to do this, but I don't know how to create this in netbeans.  I cannot edit the generated code, and the "customize code" feature doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for, but I may be wrong.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: Ken seems to grasp the concept of tables (despite his inclusion of irrelevant code). I think he's asking "how do I pass my table model to my table in NetBeans." In Eclipse, for example, you'd find the model attribute in the table's properties list and set a custom model, but I haven't touched NetBeans in years, so I can't answer the question myself.

Comment: You can use the form editor to only get you so far, at some point you going to need to get dirty with the code.  The simplest solution is to create a `TableModel` (I'd recommend from a `AbstractTableModel` as it allows you to deal directly with the objects you already have) and apply it to the table via the `JTable#setModel` method

Comment: @MarsAtomic It's still just Java code...`JTable#setModel`

Comment: Exactly, and there are **plenty** of examples of just this sort of thing to be found on this site. For example, please check out [@MadProgrammer's list of relevant answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+%5Bswing%5D+body%3Aabstracttablemodel), and also [my list of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+%5Bswing%5D+body%3Aabstracttablemodel).

Comment: Thanks for the help, gist just posted my first file instead of the link i wanted, sorry.  Also it is hard to find relevant answers when I'm very confused :P Thanks though

Comment: Here's one of @Mad's with a decent example code that will compile and run for you: [AbstractTableModel example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17538199/522444).

Answer (score 2):

Create a `TableModel` capable of managing your `Student`s...

```
public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Student> students;

    public StudentTableModel(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return students.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        Class type = Object.class;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                type = String.class;
                break;
        }
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Student student = students.get(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = student.getFirstName();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = student.getLastName();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = student.getPosition();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        String name = "";
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                name = "First name";
                break;
            case 1:
                name = "Last name";
                break;
            case 2:
                name = "Position";
                break;
        }
        return name;
    }

}
```

Then with your instance of `JTable`, apply the model to the table...

```
StudentTableModel studentModel = new StudentTableModel(...);
rosterTable.setModel(studentModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

getStr_c1() is a method of class which objects are returned by myarraylist() method.

```
jTable_a = new javax.swing.JTable();
javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel model =new
avax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
Object[] columnsName = new Object[4];
columnsName[0] = "colimn1";
columnsName[1] = "colimn2";
columnsName[2] = "colimn3";
columnsName[3] = "colimn14";
model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
Object[]rowData = new Object[4];
for(int i = 0; i < myarraylist().size(); i++){
rowData[0] = myarraylist().get(i).getStr_c1();
rowData[1] = myarraylist().get(i).getStr_c2();
rowData[2] = myarraylist().get(i).getStr_c3();
rowData[3] = myarraylist().get(i).getStr_c4();
model.addRow(rowData);
}
jTable_a.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
jTable_a.setModel(model);
```